# bash : recovery informations in line

Tags: bash, awk, grep

from a file created with a previous script, I want to retrieve my information in a certain way. Indeed, I would like to have the information of the rsID (unique), the gene name (unique) and the list of transcribed names in line.

here a part of my rsID.txt file :

```
rsID
rs142849724
rs141989890
```

here a part of my rsID_out.txt :

```
"1","rs142849724","ENSG00000228794","ENST00000624927"
"2","rs142849724","ENSG00000228794","ENST00000623808"
"3","rs142849724","ENSG00000228794","ENST00000445118"
"4","rs142849724","ENSG00000228794","ENST00000448975"
"5","rs142849724","ENSG00000228794","ENST00000610067"
"6","rs142849724","ENSG00000228794","ENST00000608189"
"7","rs142849724","ENSG00000228794","ENST00000609139"
"8","rs142849724","ENSG00000228794","ENST00000449005"
"9","rs142849724","ENSG00000228794","ENST00000416570"
"10","rs142849724","ENSG00000228794","ENST00000623070"
"11","rs142849724","ENSG00000228794","ENST00000609009"
"12","rs142849724","ENSG00000228794","ENST00000622921"
"13","rs141989890","ENSG00000228794","ENST00000624927"
"14","rs141989890","ENSG00000228794","ENST00000623808"
"15","rs141989890","ENSG00000228794","ENST00000445118"
"16","rs141989890","ENSG00000228794","ENST00000448975"
"17","rs141989890","ENSG00000228794","ENST00000610067"
"18","rs141989890","ENSG00000228794","ENST00000608189"
"19","rs141989890","ENSG00000228794","ENST00000609139"
"20","rs141989890","ENSG00000228794","ENST00000449005"
"21","rs141989890","ENSG00000228794","ENST00000416570"
"22","rs141989890","ENSG00000228794","ENST00000623070"
"23","rs141989890","ENSG00000228794","ENST00000609009"
"24","rs141989890","ENSG00000228794","ENST00000622921"
```

I created this code :

```
while read line
do
    res=`grep "$line" rsID_out.txt | awk -F ',' '!seen[$3]++ {print $3 ";"}'`
    ra=`grep "$line" rsID_out.txt | awk -F ',' '{print $4}'`
    echo "$line ; $res ; $ra"
done < rsID.txt
```

I get this file as results :

```
rs142849724 ; "ENSG00000228794" ; "ENST00000624927"
"ENST00000623808"
"ENST00000445118"
"ENST00000448975"
"ENST00000610067"
"ENST00000608189"
"ENST00000609139"
"ENST00000449005"
"ENST00000416570"
"ENST00000623070"
"ENST00000609009"
"ENST00000622921"

rs141989890 ; "ENSG00000228794" ; "ENST00000624927"
"ENST00000623808"
"ENST00000445118"
"ENST00000448975"
"ENST00000610067"
"ENST00000608189"
"ENST00000609139"
"ENST00000449005"
"ENST00000416570"
"ENST00000623070"
"ENST00000609009"
"ENST00000622921"
```

But I would like to have the file in the form:

```
rs142849724;"ENSG00000228794";"ENST00000624927"|"ENST00000623808"|"ENST00000445118"|"ENST00000448975"|"ENST00000610067"|"ENST00000608189"|"ENST00000609139"|"ENST00000449005"|"ENST00000416570"|"ENST00000623070"|"ENST00000609009"|"ENST00000622921"

rs141989890;"ENSG00000228794";"ENST00000624927"|"ENST00000623808"|"ENST00000445118"|"ENST00000448975"|"ENST00000610067"|"ENST00000608189"|"ENST00000609139"|"ENST00000449005"|"ENST00000416570"|"ENST00000623070"|"ENST00000609009"|"ENST00000622921"
```

how to do it?

Thank You

edit : I think I finally understood how to format my post. Thank you! Thank you! Indeed, I want to reorganize the rsID_out.txt to one line per rs id. Sorry if you had any problems with the incorrect formatting of my post. The file rsID.txt contains a first rsID line but no empty lines. I take note of your answers, remarks and proposals and I look yours responses.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks and do the same for your input, output, as shown in the animated image under "blocks of code" in the accepted answer to format it properly. You apparently already did that for your code as it's well-formatted.

Comment: @EdMorton Please excuse me, I think I have modified my post well

Comment: No, it's still not something we can copy/paste to test a potential solution against. Please just follow the directions I pointed you to to format your input and output the same way you did your code. Also make sure your example is minimal - it's not obvious to me why we should need to be presented with 24 lines of input to understand your problem rather than, say, 5 lines of input.

Comment: Also explain the need for the `rsID.txt` file. It looks like you're just reorganizing `rsID_out.txt` to one line per rs id present in that file and so the rsID.txt is not necessary at all.

Comment: Now just substitute newlines with `|` in the output using `sed -z` or really just `tr '\n' '|'`

Comment: Does rsID.txt actually contain a first line `rsID` and multiple blank lines? `grep "" file` will match anything

Comment: BTW, your sample output doesn't match your code: the second semicolon should be doubled (res already ends with a semicolon, so the echo should produce two)

Comment: Something you will note in contrast to your code in the two answers given so far - as noted by @jhnc: try to avoid running AWK in the body of a loop. AWK is capable of doing looping for you "for free". Also, don't pipe `grep` into `awk` - the latter is perfectly capable of regex matching on its own.

Comment: I think I finally understood how to format my post. Thank you! Thank you! Indeed, I want to reorganize the rsID_out.txt to one line per rs id.  Sorry if you had any problems with the incorrect formatting of my post. The file rsID.txt contains a first rsID line but no empty lines. I take note of your answers, remarks and proposals.

Comment: Again, please explain the purpose of the rsID.txt file as it's not needed to get the output you want from rsID_out.txt alone in your posted example.

Comment: Indeed, the rsID.txt file is useless in the end, I thought I would use it to group the different elements of each rsID but as you showed, it is possible to get the desired output without the rsID.txt file. I'm complicating the problem unnecessarily, you're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming two data files:

- **rsID.txt** containing desired rsID to locate:

```
rs142849724
rs141989890
```

- **rsID_out.txt** containing:

```
"1","rs142849724","ENSG00000228794","ENST00000624927" 
"2","rs142849724","ENSG00000228794","ENST00000623808" 
"3","rs142849724","ENSG00000228794","ENST00000445118" 
"4","rs142849724","ENSG00000228794","ENST00000448975" 
"5","rs142849724","ENSG00000228794","ENST00000610067" 
"6","rs142849724","ENSG00000228794","ENST00000608189" 
"7","rs142849724","ENSG00000228794","ENST00000609139" 
"8","rs142849724","ENSG00000228794","ENST00000449005" 
"9","rs142849724","ENSG00000228794","ENST00000416570" 
"10","rs142849724","ENSG00000228794","ENST00000623070" 
"11","rs142849724","ENSG00000228794","ENST00000609009" 
"12","rs142849724","ENSG00000228794","ENST00000622921" 
"13","rs141989890","ENSG00000228794","ENST00000624927" 
"14","rs141989890","ENSG00000228794","ENST00000623808" 
"15","rs141989890","ENSG00000228794","ENST00000445118" 
"16","rs141989890","ENSG00000228794","ENST00000448975" 
"17","rs141989890","ENSG00000228794","ENST00000610067" 
"18","rs141989890","ENSG00000228794","ENST00000608189" 
"19","rs141989890","ENSG00000228794","ENST00000609139" 
"20","rs141989890","ENSG00000228794","ENST00000449005" 
"21","rs141989890","ENSG00000228794","ENST00000416570" 
"22","rs141989890","ENSG00000228794","ENST00000623070" 
"23","rs141989890","ENSG00000228794","ENST00000609009"
"24","rs141989890","ENSG00000228794","ENST00000622921"
```

then to produce the requested output with `awk`:

```
awk -F, '
    NR==FNR {
        x[$1]++
        next
    }
    {
        gsub(/"/, "", $2)
        k = $2 ";" $3
    }
    $2 in x { a[k] = a[k] "|" $4 }
    END {
        for (k in a) {
            sub(/[|]/, "", a[k])
            print k ";" a[k]
        }
    }
' rsID.txt rsID_out.txt
```

- `NR==FNR {...}` - read the list of rsID to look for
- `gsub` - strip the doublequotes
- `k` - the key (rsID;"gene name") ?
- `$2 in x` - only process rsID in the list
- `END` - delete first pipe then print each key with its value

**Note:** This code assumes that lines need not be grouped and may appear in any order. The memory used by awk will be roughly proportional to the size of `rsID_out.txt` which may be problematic if that file is huge. The alternative awk solutions by, for example Dudi Boy and Ed Morton, do assume lines are grouped (a reasonable assumption based on the sample data provided). This allows them to only need a tiny amount of memory.

---

As suggested in the comments you could also amend your code using sed. Something like:

```
while read line; do
    res=$( grep "$line" rsID_out.txt | awk -F , '!seen[$3]++ {print $3}' )
    ra=$( grep "$line" rsID_out.txt | awk -F , '{printf "|%s", $4} END {print ""}' | sed 's/[|]//' )
    echo "$line;$res;$ra"
done < rsID.txt
```

It'll be somewhat less efficient: For every line of input, grep and awk are invoked twice and sed once, rather than just a single call to awk overall. For large amounts of data this may matter.

Comment: That shell loop at the end won't be `somewhat less efficient` - it'll literally be orders of magnitude less efficient and while it might be OK for this specific case it will in general produce false matches and corrupt the output. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/133219 for **some** of the issues.

Comment: Don't do `printf $4` btw, always `printf "%s", $4` instead - the former will fail when $4 contains printf formatting characters like `%s`. You need to add a newline at the end of the awk output as otherwise it's not a POSIX text file so YMMV with what any subsequent command will do with it. You don't need grep and/or sed when you're using awk. So, for example, `grep "$line" rsID_out.txt | awk -F , '{printf "|"$4}' | sed 's/|//'` should just be `awk -F, -v line="$line" '$0 ~ line{printf "%s%s", sep, $4; sep="|"} END{print ""}' rsID_out.txt` (but of course that could be made more robust).

Comment: Thanks @EdMorton, thought there was something wrong with the printf. As aim was to demonstrate how to tweak the code rather than to improve/rewrite it, I've just made the minimal fix.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this **might** be all you need:

```
$ cat file
"1","rs142849724","ENSG00000228794","ENST00000624927"
"2","rs142849724","ENSG00000228794","ENST00000623808"
"3","rs142849724","ENSG00000228794","ENST00000445118"
"13","rs141989890","ENSG00000228794","ENST00000624927"
"14","rs141989890","ENSG00000228794","ENST00000623808"
"15","rs141989890","ENSG00000228794","ENST00000445118"

$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=","; OFS="|" }
$2 != prev {
    if ( NR > 1 ) {
        print rec
    }
    prev = $2
    gsub(/"/,"",$2)
    rec = $2 ";" $3 ";" $4
    next
}
{ rec = rec OFS $4 }
END { print rec }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
rs142849724;"ENSG00000228794";"ENST00000624927"|"ENST00000623808"|"ENST00000445118"
rs141989890;"ENSG00000228794";"ENST00000624927"|"ENST00000623808"|"ENST00000445118"
```

if it's not all you need then update your question to clarify your requirements and provide more truly representative sample input/output.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a single `awk` script to run on the `rsID_out.txt` that will produce the required formatted data.

script.awk

```
!seen[$2""$3] {         # if new sequence of input lines
    seen[$2""$3] = 1;   # mark the new sequence
    if (rowCount++) print row; # if not first output row, print previous output row
    gsub("\"","",$2);   # clear redundant quote marks from 2nd field in input line
    row = $2";"$3";"$4; # assign 2nd and 3rd fields from input line, to new output row
    next;               # proceed to next input line
}
{ row = row"|"$4;}      # add 4th field from input line to output row
END { print row; }      # print the last output row.
```

runing the script:

```
 awk -F "," -f script.awk rsID_out.txt
```

output:

```
rs142849724;"ENSG00000228794";"ENST00000624927"|"ENST00000623808"|"ENST00000445118"|"ENST00000448975"|"ENST00000610067"|"ENST00000608189"|"ENST00000609139"|"ENST00000449005"|"ENST00000416570"|"ENST00000623070"|"ENST00000609009"|"ENST00000622921"
rs141989890;"ENSG00000228794";"ENST00000624927"|"ENST00000623808"|"ENST00000445118"|"ENST00000448975"|"ENST00000610067"|"ENST00000608189"|"ENST00000609139"|"ENST00000449005"|"ENST00000416570"|"ENST00000623070"|"ENST00000609009"|"ENST00000622921"
```

Please post comments about the output format and logic.

Notice the 1st field and 2nd fields delimiter is `;` while 3rd field to last field delimiter is `|`

Comment: Don't you need to set FS somewhere?

Comment: `$2""$3` = `$2$3`, `ab c` = `abc`, and `a bc` = `abc`. The points are: 1), using `""` between strings during concatenation does nothing and, 2) you need to put **something** non-null between strings during concatenation to form unique keys. So use `$2 FS $3` or `$2 OFS $3` or `$2 SUBSEP $3` depending on whether or not you want to print the resultant key later and, if so, what value should separate it's components and/or whether or not you later want to use `array[$2,$3]` or `($2,$3) in array` to test for it's existence.